# Inserting data into a table in MySQL with PyMySQL

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

I tried to insert some data into a table like this as below, but it doesn't work for me.

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='1234', charset='utf8', db='kobis')
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = """insert into 'boxoffice' (targetDt, rank, rankOldAndNew, 
                                  movieCd, movieNm, salesAmt, audiCnt)
         values (%d, %d, %s, %d, %s, %d, %d) % cur.execute(sql, 
                   (20180220,11,'OLD',20170511,'Conan',36388900,48011))
    """

conn.commit()
```

There doesn't come out any error message after running this code, but the new data I tried to insert doesn't show up in the table 'boxoffice' at all...

Does anyone have a good idea to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to execute your sql, you missed that line:

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='1234', charset='utf8', db='kobis')
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = """insert into `boxoffice` (targetDt, rank, rankOldAndNew, 
                                  movieCd, movieNm, salesAmt, audiCnt)
         values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) 
    """
cur.execute(sql,(20180220,11,'OLD',20170511,'Conan',36388900,48011))
conn.commit()
```

**EDIT**
Yor cur.execute() was inside the `sql` string, so it was doing nothing

Comment: I changed the python code as you suggested, but it still doesn't work for me.

The error message is like this:
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''boxoffice' (targetDt,rank,rankOldAndNew,movieCd,movieNm,salesAmt,audiCnt)\n    v' at line 1")

Comment: the version of MySQL program in my PC is 8.0.15

Comment: It's about the quotation marks around the table name boxoffice. You can remove them or use `boxoffice` with the reverse quotation marks. I change the answer

Comment: I fixed a little bit of my original code around 'sql'. And it did work.

    sql = "Insert into `korea` (`targetDt`, `rank`, `rankOldAndNew`, `movieCd`, `movieNm`, `salesAmt`, `audiCnt`) " \
          + " values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) "

Answer (score 0):

for me the problem was not adding a \n please do something like this:

```
sql = f"INSERT INTO audits ({fields})"+ "\n" +  f"VALUES ({values})"
```

I hope this helps others cracked my head on this issue for over 2 hours.

Comment: Why would you have to split your query in two lines...? A space would do, no?